# GridSearchCV does not give the same results as expected when compared to xgboost.cv

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, grid-search

when comparing sklearn.GridSearchCV with xgboost.cv I get different results...below I explain what I would like to do:

1) import libraries

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
```

2) set seed and folds

```
seed = 5
n_fold_inner = 5
skf_inner               = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_fold_inner,random_state=seed, shuffle=True)
```

3) load dataset

```
X, y = datasets.make_hastie_10_2(n_samples=12000, random_state=1)
X = X.astype(np.float32)

# map labels from {-1, 1} to {0, 1}
labels, y = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True)

X_train, X_test = X[:2000], X[2000:]
y_train, y_test = y[:2000], y[2000:]
dtrain  = xgb.DMatrix(X_train,  label=y_train, missing = np.nan)
```

4) define parameters xgboost

```
fixed_parameters = {
               'max_depth':3,
               'min_child_weight':3,
               'learning_rate':0.3,
               'colsample_bytree':0.8,
               'subsample':0.8,
               'gamma':0,
               'max_delta_step':0,
               'colsample_bylevel':1,
               'reg_alpha':0,
               'reg_lambda':1,
               'scale_pos_weight':1,
               'base_score':0.5,
               'seed':5,
               'objective':'binary:logistic',
               'silent': 1}
```

5) parameters for wich I do the grid search (only one, ie the number of estimators)

```
params_grid = {
               'n_estimators':np.linspace(1, 20, 20).astype('int')
               }
```

6) perform grid search

```
bst_grid = GridSearchCV(
            estimator=XGBClassifier(**fixed_parameters),param_grid=params_grid,n_jobs=4,
            cv=skf_inner,scoring='roc_auc',iid=False,refit=False,verbose=1)

bst_grid.fit(X_train,y_train)

best_params_grid_search = bst_grid.best_params_
best_score_grid_search = bst_grid.best_score_


means_train = bst_grid.cv_results_['mean_train_score']
stds_train = bst_grid.cv_results_['std_train_score']
means_test = bst_grid.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds_test = bst_grid.cv_results_['std_test_score']
```

7) print results

```
print('\ntest-auc-mean  test-auc-std  train-auc-mean  train-auc-std')
for idx in range(0, len(means_test)):
    print means_test[idx], stds_test[idx], means_train[idx], stds_train[idx]
```

8) now I run xgb.cv with the same parameters of before for 20 rounds (the n_estimators that I was giving as input to the gridsearch before. The problem is that I get different results...

```
num_rounds = 20
best_params_grid_search['objective']= 'binary:logistic'
best_params_grid_search['silent']= 1
cv_xgb = xgb.cv(best_params_grid_search,dtrain,num_boost_round =num_rounds,folds=skf_inner,metrics={'auc'},seed=seed,maximize=True)
print(cv_xgb)
```

RESULT GRIDSEARCH (each row is using n estimators (1,2,3,...,20)

```
test-auc-mean  test-auc-std  train-auc-mean  train-auc-std
0.610051313783 0.0161039540435 0.644057288587 0.0113345992869
0.69201880047 0.0162563563448 0.736006666658 0.00692672815659
0.745466211655 0.0171675737271 0.796345885396 0.00696679302744
0.783959748994 0.00705320521545 0.841463145757 0.00948465661336
0.814666429161 0.0205663250121 0.876016226998 0.00594191823748
0.834757856446 0.0380407635359 0.89839145346 0.0119466187041
0.846589877247 0.0250769570711 0.918506450202 0.00400934458132
0.856519550489 0.02076405634 0.929968936282 0.00287173282935
0.874262106553 0.0270140215944 0.940190511945 0.00335749381638
0.884796282407 0.0242102758081 0.947369708661 0.00274634034559
0.890833683342 0.0240690598159 0.953708404754 0.00332080069217
0.898287157179 0.0212975975614 0.958794323829 0.00463360376002
0.905931348284 0.0240526927266 0.963055575138 0.00385161158711
0.911782932073 0.0169788764956 0.966542306102 0.00274612227499
0.912551138778 0.0175200936415 0.969060984867 0.00135518880398
0.915046588665 0.0169918459539 0.971904231381 0.00177694652262
0.917921423036 0.0131486037603 0.975162276052 0.0025983006922
0.921909172729 0.0113192686772 0.976056924526 0.0022670828819
0.928131653291 0.0117709832599 0.978585868159 0.00211167800105
0.931493562339 0.0119475329984 0.98098486872 0.00186032225868
```

RESULT XGB.CV

```
    test-auc-mean  test-auc-std  train-auc-mean  train-auc-std
0        0.669881      0.013938        0.772116       0.011315
1        0.759682      0.019225        0.883394       0.004381
2        0.798337      0.016992        0.939274       0.005196
3        0.827751      0.007224        0.962461       0.007382
4        0.850340      0.011451        0.978809       0.001102
5        0.864438      0.020012        0.986584       0.000858
6        0.879706      0.014168        0.991765       0.001926
7        0.889308      0.013851        0.994663       0.000970
8        0.897973      0.011383        0.996704       0.000481
9        0.903878      0.012139        0.997494       0.000432
10       0.909599      0.010234        0.998301       0.000602
11       0.912682      0.014475        0.998972       0.000306
12       0.914289      0.014122        0.999392       0.000207
13       0.916273      0.011744        0.999568       0.000185
14       0.918050      0.011219        0.999718       0.000140
15       0.922161      0.011968        0.999788       0.000146
16       0.922990      0.010124        0.999863       0.000085
17       0.924221      0.009026        0.999893       0.000082
18       0.925718      0.008859        0.999929       0.000060
19       0.926104      0.007586        0.999959       0.000030
```

Answer (score 1):

**num_boost_round** is the number of boosting iterations **(i.e. n_estimators)**. XGBoost.cv will ignore n_estimators from params and overwrit it by num_boost_round.

Try this:

```
cv_xgb = xgb.cv(best_params_grid_search,dtrain,num_boost_round =best_params_grid_search['n_estimators'],folds=skf_inner,metrics={'auc'},seed=seed,maximize=True)
```